# How can I implement low latency HLS?

Tags: nginx, streaming, http-live-streaming, rtmp

Recently Apple announced low-latency HLS. I watched the presentation and didn't understand how I can implement that. I have already setup the nginx server with rtmp module and configured HLS. The latency is about 30 secs. So what should I change/update my nginx config file or player? Thanks

Comment: ALHS is so new, none of the tools support it yet. You would need to modify ffmpeg to support the manifest changes and segmenter changes, and modify nginx to be aware of the new URL parameters. and by modify, I mean write the code, not change a setting.

Comment: may be other options to achieve low latency?

Comment: like webrtc for example?

Comment: @szatmary But how can I use WebRTC for broadcasting to many people? Or how can transfer the rtmp stream to WebRTC?

Comment: If you have a new question. Please make a new post.